# Command Line Argument (how to reserve the next argument for a parameter labeled)

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am curious to know how simple something like this would be.. Hard-coding each argument into place is tedious to troubleshoot, and I'm not exactly sure how argument parsing works, beyond that of looping through them.

Such as

```
public static Main(string args[])
{
     for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
     {
          if(args[i] == "-path")
          {
               path = args[i++];
          }
     //bleh
     }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing a simple concept in using loops, such as increments..?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the temporary route I'm taking. I may switch it. But now I get *Empty path name is not valid*

```
for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
{
    if(args[0] == "-logpath" && (args[1].Contains("%") || args[1].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[1].Contains("\\")))
    {
        logpath = args[1];
    }
    if(args[2] == "-idpath" && (args[3].Contains("%") || args[3].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[3].Contains("\\")))
    {
        serverIDpath = args[3];
    }
    if(args[4] == "-queuepath" && (args[5].Contains("%") || args[5].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[5].Contains("\\")))
    {
        servqueuepath = args[5];
    }
    if(args[6] == "-ramlimit" && 0 < Convert.ToInt32(args[7]))
    {
        ramlimit = args[7];
    }
    if(args[8] == "-paramsname" && (!args[11].Contains("\\") || !args[11].Contains(":")) && (args[11].Contains(".cmd") || args[11].ToLower().Contains(".txt") || args[11].Contains("bat")))
    {
        spname = args[9];
    }
    if(args[10] == "-idname" && (!args[11].Contains("\\") || !args[11].Contains(":")) && (args[11].Contains(".cmd") || args[11].ToLower().Contains(".txt") || args[11].Contains("bat")))
    {
        sidname = args[111];
    }
    if(args[12] == "-resourcetxtpath" && (args[13].Contains("%") || args[13].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[13].Contains("\\")))
    {
        resourcetxt = args[13];
    }
    if(args[14] == "-sysresource" && (args[15].Contains("%") || args[15].ToUpper().Contains("C") || args[15].Contains("\\")))
    {
        ramoutput = args[15];
    }
    if(args[16] == "-updatepath" && (args[17].Contains("%") || args[17].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[17].Contains("\\")))
    {
        makeserverpath = args[17];
    }
    if(args[18] == "-servelogpath" && (args[19].Contains("%") || args[19].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[19].Contains("\\")))
    {
        Logpath = args[19];
    }
    if(args[20] == "-fileserve" && (args[21].Contains("%") || args[21].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[21].Contains("\\")))
    {
        fileservepath = args[21];
    }
}
```

batch file:

```
set rootpath=%userprofile%\desktop
cd "%rootpath%
fileread -logpath %rootpath%\fr_log.txt -idpath %rootpath%\ -queuepath %rootpath%\queuecheck.txt -ramlimit 1600 -paramsname serverparams.cmd -idname serverid.cmd -resourcetxtpath %rootpath%\ramcheck.txt -sysresource %rootpath%\sysresourceoutput.exe -updatepath %rootpath%\update.bat -servelogpath %rootpath%\fsrv_log.txt -fileserve %rootpath%\FileServe.exe
```

Comment: Your example seems about right. What more do you need? What I would do in addition is to check if each option has an associated value. That is, make sure that `args[i++]` does not get an invalid reference. Never trust the user's input...

Comment: I may take that route. Haha, and disregard the " before %rootpath% and args[111]

Comment: Maybe I will make a new question. I haven't found the missing path happenstance yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cool project on [Codeplex - Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/)which does the argument parsing for you.(NuGet Package: Install-Package CommandLineParser)

Comment: I will use this.. eventually.